# unable to execute "python -m py_compile" commnd

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to python, I tried compiling some open source from git, and executed some shell scripts using jenkins pipeline.

my jenkins code:

```
pipeline
{
    agent any
    stages
    {
        stage("Git-Clone")
        
        {
            steps{
            git 'https://github.com/Vsb19/simple-python-pyinstaller-app.git'
            }
        }
        stage('Shell scripts')
        {
            steps
            {
                sh  'python -m py_compile sources/add2vals.py sources/calc.py'
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

after running I am getting issue like:

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ python -m py_compile sources/add2vals.py sources/calc.py
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sample-python@tmp/durable-b12d65e6/script.sh: 1: python: not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

I installed java, python, pip, Jenkins in my ubuntu vm

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the `python` executable isn't in the `$PATH` of the jenkins user. Using the fullpath should solve it, e.g.:

```
sh  '/usr/bin/python -m py_compile sources/add2vals.py sources/calc.py'
```

Comment: tried it, now am getting this issue
"/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sample-python@tmp/durable-d7f733b6/script.sh: 2: /var/lib/python: Permission denied"